# iphone 6s camera calibration parameters

Tags: iphone, camera, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, slam

How can I get camera calibration parameters for iphone 6s? I need the following intrinsic parameters:

Cam_fx: normalized focal length in x

Cam_fy: normalized focal length in y

Cam_cx: normalized camera center in x

Cam_cy: normalized camera center in y

Cam_s: normalized distortion factor

I tried using the [PTAM](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration) camera calibration process but im getting some errors. Can anyone please suggest me some other way?

Comment: "I'm getting some errors" is not very helpful. Internet provides plenty of information and solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these parameters can be calculate with an intrinsic calibration process, which is available in either Matlab Camera Calibration Toolbox or OpenCV library.

Answer (score 0):

Though a calibration process using opencv, matlab app, or matlab toolbox surely works, I have to point out that cameras on iphone are almost IDENTICAL (same focal length, same distortion, and so on), due to maybe the astonishing manufacturing quality control.